# PHP - take value from database and set as value of HTML select tag

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

Hope someone can help me out.
Developing a stock management system for a herb factory in PHP with a MySQL database. I'm currently developing a page where the user can edit the value of one of the benches that holds the herbs.

I've drawn in the benches details and they're in an array called `$bench_data` which contains variable `herb`, `quantity`, etc.

I have a html select tag where the user selects the herb being produced

```
Herb*:<br>
<select name='herb' ">
   <option value="default">-----</option>
   <option value="basil">Basil</option>
   <option value="coriander">Coriander</option>
   <option value="parsley">Parsley</option>
   <option value="mint">Mint</option>
   <option value="rosemary">Rosemary</option>
   <option value="thyme">Thyme</option>
</select>
```

What I want to do is have the herb value of the selected bench already in the select tag when the user enters the page.

I've managed to do it with quantity - 'the php in value'

```
Quanity<br>
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $bench_data['quantity']; ?>">
```

but I don't know how to do it when there are different `option`s

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the "selected" attribute to tell the browser which option should be showing on page load. For example, on each option do it like this:

```
<option value="basil" <?php if ($bench_data['herb']=='basil'){echo 'selected';}?>>
Basil
</option>
```

Here's a helpful [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

Comment: or use single if statement. `<option value="basil" <?php echo $bench_data['herb']=='basil' ? 'selected':'';?>>
Basil</option>`